# Ruta correcta para FileManager en Laravel

Tags: laravel, imagen

estoy hecho un lío con las rutas para hacer funcionar UniSharp/laravel-filemanager en el servidor. En modo local me funciona a la perfección pero al hacer el cambio de rutas para producción en modo online no lo tengo nada claro.

El problema es que carga las imágenes pero no se visualizan ni en la página, ni en el propio filemanager. En el propio filemanager se ve un cuadrado en rojo con una cruz (a modo de error en la carga). A ver si alguien conoce de qué modo se ponen las rutas, porque he probado muchas cosas y no me aclaro.

El árbol de la página estaría compuesto por la app de laravel en la raíz del hosting y luego una carpeta public_html dónde iría el resto de carpetas públicas de laravel.

El archivo filesystem.php de config en Laravel:

```
'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('public_html'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],
    ],
  'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

En el archivo lfm.php de filemanager tiene la ruta de subida predeterminada:

```
'disk'  => 'public',
```

Y por si aclara algo más, así apunta mi index.php en public_html

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../mi_app_laravel/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../mi_app_laravel/storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}
require __DIR__.'/../mi_app_laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../mi_app_laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Y en ServiceProviders:

```
   public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path().'/public_html';
        });
    }
```

¿Cómo debería poner la ruta en filesystem para que filemanager pueda acceder a ellas y mostrar imágenes?
P.D: la carpeta public_html dispone del enlace simbólico a storage.

Answer (score 1):

Como te he indicado en el comentario, te facilito un código base para que puedas mostrar archivos mediante un Controlador.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class FileController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Requerimos que el usuario esté logueado para que pueda acceder a los métodos del controlador (Eliminar la linea inferior para no requerir login)
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function getFile($folder,$file)
    {
            $fullpath= "/{$folder}/{$file}";
            $fileContent = Storage::disk('local')->get($fullpath);
            return response()->streamDownload(function() use($fileContent) {
                echo $fileContent;
              }, $file);
        
    }
    public function getFilesubfolder($folder,$subfolder,$file)
    {
            $fullpath= "/{$folder}/{$subfolder}/{$file}"; 
            $fileContent = Storage::disk('local')->get($fullpath);
            return response()->streamDownload(function() use($fileContent) {
                echo $fileContent;
              }, $file);
    }
    public function getFileUrl($folder,$file)
    {
            $fullpath= "/{$folder}/{$file}";
            // No se si el método "temporaryUrl" funciona en un disco local, así que te lo dejo comentado
            //$fileContent1 = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($fullpath, now()->addMinutes(5));
            //return $fileContent1;
            $fileContent = Storage::disk('local')->get($fullpath);
            return response()->streamDownload(function() use($fileContent) {
                echo $fileContent;
              }, $file);
            
        
    }
    public function getFilesubfolderUrl($folder,$subfolder,$file)
    {   
            $fullpath= "/{$folder}/{$subfolder}/{$file}"; 
            // No se si el método "temporaryUrl" funciona en un disco local, así que te lo dejo comentado
            //$fileContent1 = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($fullpath, now()->addMinutes(5));
            //return $fileContent1;
            $fileContent = Storage::disk('local')->get($fullpath);
            return response()->streamDownload(function() use($fileContent) {
                echo $fileContent;
              }, $file);
    }
    // Este va de regalo  (Es devolver archivos que se encuentran fuera de Storage)
    public function getFileOutside($foldername,$filename)
    {
        $fullpath= "app/{$foldername}/{$filename}";
        return response()->download(storage_path($fullpath), null, [], null);
    }
}
```

Te explico brevemente los métodos:

- Los Métodos "getFile" te devuelven directamente el archivo
- Los Métodos "getFileUrl" te devuelven una url (temporal* o no) que pueden incrustar en las vistas
- (extra) El Método "getFileOutside" devuelve un archivo que se encuentra fuera de storage

*Las urls temporales sólo se pueden generar mediante drivers de discos externos (Amazon S3, Google GCS, etc.) desconozco si hay alguna manera "no oficial" de generar links temporales en el disco local, así que te dejo ese código comentado

Los metodos tienen una variante con "subfolder" porque se requiere colocar correctamente el nombre de las carpetas para Storage, así que paso la carpeta requerida en la url.

Las rutas para acceder a estos métodos podrían ser algo asi:

routes/app.php:

```
...
use App\Http\Controllers\FileController;
...
Route::get('/rutasuperchula/archivos/{folder}/novasaaccederaqui/{file}', [FileController::class, 'getFile'])->name('file.getfile');
...
```

En la vista (para el caso de los métodos que devuelvan URL) simplemente:
`{{route('file.getfileUrl',['folder'=>$carpeta, 'file'=>$archivo])}}`

Espero haberte ayudado y este Controlador te sirva

Comment: Me sirve de precedente, estudio, y teoría. Así que de 10. Mil gracias por el aporte y el tiempo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he revisado y he aplicado algunos cambios, ahora parece que funciona correctamente, pero no me convence que el usuario pueda ver la ruta de la imagen y que pueda ver la ruta completa de un directorio cuya ruta debería ser privada.

Cambios:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    /* Esto */  'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    /* Esto */  'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/public',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Con esos cambios ya se podrían ver y subir las imágenes. El problema es el tema de la ruta, es decir, al clikar en la imagen el usuario puede ver su ruta:

```
http//mi_lar_app/storage/app/public/photos/31/art_1/fig_1.0.png
```

**Algo que hacer ante esto????**

Y para quién tuviera el mismo problema anterior, le dejo lo que hice para resolverlo:

```
<?php
    /*__DIR__ es el directorio donde se encuentra este file.php */
    /* __DIR__ en mi caso esta en public_html */
    $storefile       = __DIR__.'/../mi_lar_app/storage';
    $linktostorefile = __DIR__.'/storage';
    symlink($storefile,$linktostorefile);
    echo 'Enlace OK';
?>
```

Y otra cosa, es importante limpiar caché, rutas y demás, y sin acceso SSH hice lo mismo que antes, crear clean.php ->

```
<?php
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    Artisan::call('route:cache');
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
      return 'Todo limpio';
?>
```

Estos dos archivos al public_html y los visitas. No olvides borrarlos cuando pongas accesible la app, o si lo necesitas, mételos en una ruta protegida con auth o similar.

Y después de este inciso, alguien que pueda echarme un cable?? :)

**EDICIÓN Resuelto tras el comentario de @EdgarBorrásCarcelén**

Comment: Puedes crear un Controlador que se encargue de todas las imágenes con rutas personalizadas e incluso crear roles para controlar el acceso de imágenes en el mismo controlador. Podrías guardar las imágenes en el disco local de Storage (Que no es accesible por defecto)  y devolver la imagen mediante una url personalizada (la ruta que indiques para que acceda al método de dicho controlador)

Comment: Genial. Había pensado algo así de tanto leer por internet cosas similares, pero no sabía si esa forma era factible para lo que busco.

Comment: Si si claro, te preparo un Controlador genérico para que veas como lo suelo hacer. Presumiblemente debas reiniciar los datos del storage a los de fábrica o por lo menos a unos datos que te permitan acceder mediante el controlador pero no mediante url ;). Te lo pongo en respuesta en unos minutos <3

Comment: @José Esto ***NO*** es tu pregunta... se supone que debe ser una respuesta. Por favor, no uses las respuestas para añadir aclaraciones u otras preguntas, para eso [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/415172/edit). Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [answer], y que prestes atención al [tour] si deseas participar en la comunidad. No tenemos muchas reglas pero es ***MUY*** importante usar correctamente las preguntas y respuestas para que todo el conocimiento esté accesible a la mayor cantidad de gente posible :)